# JavaScript file not loading - syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MyPage</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/FileFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and this "FileFunctions.js" file

```
function addField(){
  $('form input:file').last().after($('<p><input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" /><br /></p>'));
};
```

but if I load the page, my file "FileFunctions.js" is not loaded... The javascript console says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < FileFunctions.js:1
```

but I can't find out what is wrong with these codes... Thanks for any ideas

Comment: is the slash(/) before the scripts/FileFunctions.js is your intension? just to be sure

Comment: My guess is your web server isn't serving the file you expect and is serving a `404 Not Found` page full of HTML content instead of JavaScript code. Have you used Firebug to ensure the file you're downloading is the file you're expecting to download?

Comment: Have you tried using JSLint? http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen It shouldn't matter if it's a 404. The browser won't attempt to parse it, and therefore won't throw an error

Comment: @jackchuka yes it's my intension

Comment: There is CLEARLY something wrong with your server, as I repeated exactly everything and it works.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen yes that's it... I've added RewriteRules to my .htaccess file and now I'm getting my custom HTML page telling me that there is no file scripts.php instead of my js file... Thank you for that answer! I've spent about 2 hours looking for solution... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with wrong configuration in .htaccess. The apache returned my HTML page with info about non existing "scripts.php" file instead of "/scripts/FileFunctions.js".

Solution is simple, I've just added RewriteCond to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !scripts/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your javascript. Try the code below

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonocairns/Z2C9Y/1/

```
"use strict";
function addField() {
    $('form input:file').last().after('<p><input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" /><br /></p>');
};
```

Comment: it's working without your `"use strict"` as well! See http://jsfiddle.net/Z2C9Y/2/

Comment: I would strongly recommend always using "use strict". It makes development and debugging much easier! :)

Comment: Yes! Quote from MDN -> "Strict mode makes several changes to normal JavaScript semantics. First, strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors. Second, strict mode fixes mistakes that make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations: strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical code that's not strict mode. Third, strict mode prohibits some syntax likely to be defined in future versions of ECMAScript." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Comment: Thank you for answer but I've already solved it - @Richard JP Le Guen gave me nice hint that solved my problem :) I had badly configured .htaccess that returned html file instead of jscript.